# Two queries on Sybase giving different result

Tags: sybase

Below are two proc running in sybase.  The first has param name with value, the second only value.  The first one runs fine, but when I run the second I get `Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query`  Can someone tell me why?

First:

`exec pu @a=null, @b=null, @c=null, @d=null, @e=null, @f=null, @g='2013-Jun-12 22:10:00.670', @h=100, @i=2, @j=null, @k=null, @l=null, @m=null, @n=0, @o='P', @p=null, @q=null, @r=null, @s=null, @t='junit', @u=null, @v=null, @w=null`

Second:

`exec pu ( null, null, null, null, null, null, '2013-Jun-12 22:10:00.187', 100, 2, null, null, null, null, 0, 'P', null, null, null, null, 'junit', null, null, null )`

Comment: first                                                                            exec pu 
    @a=null,
    @b=null,
    @c=null,
    @d=null,
    @e=null,
    @f=null,
    @g='2013-Jun-12 22:10:00.670',
    @h=100,
    @i=2,
    @j=null,
    @k=null,
    @l=null,
    @m=null,
    @n=0,
    @o='P',
    @p=null,
    @q=null,
    @r=null,
    @s=null,
    @t='junit',
    @u=null,
    @v=null,
    @w=null

Comment: second                                                                                   
    exec pu (
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null,
    null,
    '2013-Jun-12 22:10:00.187', 
    100, 
    2, 
    null,
    null,
    null, 
    null,
    0, 
    'P', 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    'junit', 
    null, 
    null, 
    null
    )

Comment: first query running fine but second giving Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You need to use `edit` option to complete the question.

Comment: The calls appear to be the same, so we will need to see the stored procedure `pu` to be able to help you.  FYI, that error is raised when a character value is missing quotes in the insert command.

Answer (score 1):

What could also be happening is that the parameters are not defined in the same as order as you are expecting them.

In scenario 1, you won't see a problem since parameters are referenced by name.

In scenario 2 however you are using positional reference which could be exposing this issue.

Please check the proc definition and make sure parameters are declared in same order as expected.